# How to set maxConnections in ActiveMQ outbound bridge?

Tags: activemq-classic, ibm-mq

I have an ActiveMQ instance bridging incoming messages to WebsphereMQ. How can I control the number of connections used by ActiveMQ to connect to WebsphereMQ?

According to http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21665128 it seems like I have to write my own connection pool, but then what is the default behaviour?

My Spring config for the bridge:

```
<bean id="wmqConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
    <property name="queueManager" value="queueManager"/>
    <property name="connectionNameList" value="connectionNameList"/>
    <property name="channel" value="channel"/>
    <property name="transportType">
        <util:constant static-field="com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT"/>
    </property>
    <property name="clientID" value="clientID"/>
</bean>

<bean id="cachedWmqConnectionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
        <ref local="wmqConnectionFactory" />
    </property>
    <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true" />
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="1" />
</bean>

<bean id="wmqPatchedJmsConnector" class="org.apache.activemq.network.jms.JmsQueueConnector">
    <property name="name" value="ActiveMq-WMQ-Bridge"/>
    <property name="outboundQueueConnectionFactory" ref="cachedWmqConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="outboundQueueBridges">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.apache.activemq.network.jms.OutboundQueueBridge"><constructor-arg value="q1"/></bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="inboundQueueBridges"><list/></property>
</bean>

<amq:broker useJmx="true" brokerName="${activemq.brokername:my-amq}" dataDirectory="${activemq.datadirectory}" persistent="true">
    <amq:destinationPolicy>
        <amq:policyMap>
            <amq:policyEntries>
                <amq:policyEntry queue="&gt;" queuePrefetch="1">
                    <amq:deadLetterStrategy>
                        <amq:individualDeadLetterStrategy queuePrefix="DLQ." useQueueForQueueMessages="true" />
                    </amq:deadLetterStrategy>
                </amq:policyEntry>
            </amq:policyEntries>
        </amq:policyMap>
    </amq:destinationPolicy>

    <amq:jmsBridgeConnectors>
        <ref bean="jmsConnector"/>
    </amq:jmsBridgeConnectors>

    <amq:managementContext>
        <amq:managementContext createConnector="false" />
    </amq:managementContext>

    <amq:transportConnectors>
        <amq:transportConnector name="humble-transport"
            uri="${local.host}" discoveryUri="${multicastGroup}"
            updateClusterClients="true" rebalanceClusterClients="true"
            updateClusterClientsOnRemove="true" />
    </amq:transportConnectors>
</amq:broker>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour would be that every time you make a JmsConnection a new MQ Connection would be made. As you say you can implement your own layer to reuse connections instead of regularly closing them and making new ones.

If by "control" you actually mean, "stop from having too many" you should look into the MAXINST and MAXINSTC parameters on your SVRCONN.